# Open sorting dialog box via VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel (via VBA) I preselect a range and set certain predefined sorting options. Instead of executing the sorting via VBA I want to display the dialog box as it would be when clicking on the sorting button in the ribbon.

This way the user would have the option to check the sorting settings and change them if necessary.

Here's a screen shot of what I mean. I marked the button and the dialog box with a red circle. Ignore the enabled filter, it should work if the filter is disabled as well:
[image]

Comment: You want the filter button to be clicked or you want a new modal window to appear somewhere that has the same options and functionality as the filter dropdown menu? The latter would be way, way too broad to ask about, but the former might be pretty simple.

Comment: @TylerH sorry, my fault, I ment the "sorting" button, not the filter button. If the button is clicked that should suffice. Can I just trigger a click event through VBA? I never experimented with buttons on the ribbon so far.

Comment: I believe you can, but if you just want to sort A to Z you can skip the sorting button action and just issue the command via VBA. Or do you want to give the user the option of how to sort?

Comment: @TylerH yeah, the preselection done by the VBA code is supposed to be checked and tweaked by the user, so I need the dialogue to come up.

Comment: @TylerH JohnyL beat you to the punch, sorry, you are welcome to post a second answer, I will accept yours it since you were first to answer.

Comment: No worries; if Johny's works, then let him have the spotlight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "SortCustomExcel"
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I found the [MS reference entry here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.CommandBars.ExecuteMso), but I can not find a list of all the identifiers. How do I find out the name of the identifier for other buttons like "advanced filter" etc.?

Comment: @Albin You can get controls IDs [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCk0i16AZk3inmKhgi) - this is where I took ID from. Note that this is for Excel 2007. You can also search IDs like `Excel Control IDs` or something like that. Good luck! 

Comment: The document you liked to can not be accessed without a password. But searching for Excel Control IDs did the trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Albin ZIP file doesn't have password. File you need is named `ExcelRibbonControls.xlsx`.

Comment: @Albin Try [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCk0kYWyPTTPxQ1UQl) link

Comment: still no access to the file, you need to log in and if I log in with my account I can not access it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185662/discussion-between-johnyl-and-albin).

Comment: Don't see you in chat. Try [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/13gllynwz4y92if/ExcelRibbonControls.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: @Albin Glad that helped! If you have some questions, I am in chat now. 